# deploy with Capistrano takes too long at each modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

So the problem is that when I modify a file, I have to run again the cap deploy command to push the changes to the server, but it seems to me that each deploy is running all over again, I mean all the files from app are pushed to server. Is there any configurations in deploy.rb to tell capistrano to deploy only the modified ones. I am using a repository on github and what is the point of git gui if it pushes all the app all over again. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set :deploy_via, :remote_cache`

[Reasonably decent docs are here.](http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/)

Comment: but I have one deploy_via, :copy  should I delete this one?  I just tried it, very fast, thanks

Comment: Yes, get rid of the `:copy`. That means "make a local tarball, gzip it, and push it to the server", which is what you're trying to avoid in your question.

Comment: You're welcome. Capistrano docs are virtually non-existent, but keep asking good questions like this if you run into trouble.

Comment: you should not use deploy_via copy if you have slow internet. its suck